# SQl Having and round Datatype

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting sucks on this program I made

```
Select FirstName|' '|LastName as Customer_Name ,sum(price) as SubTotal, 
sum(round(MaxPrice - MinPrice),2), (price + (MaxPrice - Minprice)) as Total 
from People join Customer_Owner 
on People.PeopleId = Customer_Owner.PeopleId  join Orders 
on People.PeopleId = Orders.CustomerId  join Order_Item 
on Orders.OrderId = Order_Item.OrderId  join Item 
on Order_Item.ItemId = Item.ItemId 
group by FirstName,LastName having city = 'Clinton' order by LastName;
```

the output is supposed to look like this but whenever I run my code it is giving me a having error and it is also giving me a sum/round error.

```
Customer Name                   Subtotal     Sales Tax  Total
```

---

```
Patricia Jones                  48.00        2.88       50.88     
Paul Jones                      19.70        1.18       20.88     
Tara Roswell                    4.49         0.27       4.76      
Simon Tara                      145.00       8.70       153.70    
Theodore Turner                 16.25        0.98       17.23
```

Comment: You can't possibly be getting results from the query you posted. There are syntax errors. For example, the ROUND function requires two arguments so this would never parse and you would not get results. Also FirstName|' '|LastName is not valid syntax. Maybe that should be FirstName + ' ' + LastName Some formatting and aliases would make this manageable.

Comment: Your 'having' clause should be a 'where' clause.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like misplaced parentheses?

Change

```
sum(round(MaxPrice - MinPrice),2),
```

to

```
sum(round(MaxPrice - MinPrice,2)),
```

Answer (score 0):

*It Can be solved as below by converting the datatype to numeric*

> sum(round(cast(MaxPrice - MinPrice) as numeric(36,2)), (price + (MaxPrice - Minprice))) as Total

Let me know if it doesn't works